# Mouse positioning in Openlayers 3

Tags: openlayers-3

I want to ask why there are some div created in target div, I use openlayers 3 and my code:

```
var _showMousePositioning = function () {
    /* mouse positioning */
    this._mousePositionControl = new ol.control.MousePosition({
        coordinateFormat: function (coordinate) {
            return ol.coordinate.format(coordinate, '{y} / {x}', 4);
        },
        projection: 'EPSG:4326',
        // comment the following two lines to have the mouse position
        // be placed within the map.
        className: 'custom-mouse-position',
        target: document.getElementById('mouse-position'),
        undefinedHTML: '&nbsp;'
    });
    this._olMap.addControl(this._mousePositionControl);

    $('.custom-mouse-position:nth-child(1)').hide();
}
```

The result :

```
<div id ="mouse-position">
<div class="custom-mouse-position"> </div>
<div class="custom-mouse-position"> </div>
<div class="custom-mouse-position"> </div>
</div>
```

sometimes it create 2 or 3 div...The value of mouse positioning at the last div..how to remove another div which contain white space.There is any way to remove another div? thanks

Comment: Each time you fire the mouse position function you add a new control to the map and thus a new div will be added to your map. How often this function gets fired??????

Comment: this function only fired once when I setup a map. No another code fired _showMousePositioning.

Comment: After I investigate this case, this happen because I call the function more than once, so every I fired this function it will create a new div like pavlos said....Thanks for your information pavlos

Comment: No worries, I was pretty sure that was your case. Glad to help!